# R Redefining base::mean() function to include is.finite() functionality

Tags: r, function, mean

I would like to redefine the mean function (to apply it in a tabular() table) for it to omit all NA, NaN and Inf observations for a certain variable. I don't want to delete the whole row (observation) but rather have the mean formular simply calculate the mean for all values that are not NA, NaN, Inf.

```
Mean.new <- function(x) base::mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
```

As far as I know does na.rm=TRUE in the standard mean() only remove NAs, not NaN and Inf.

Therefore, how do I add to the code above the functionality to check for is.finite() (which would exclude all NA, NaN, Inf)?

Thank you and best,

cork

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `is.finite`:

```
mean_new <- function(x) {mean(x[is.finite(x)])}

mean_new(c(NA,Inf,NaN,1,2))

[1] 1.5
```

Answer (score 3):

Base R defines a default method for the generic `mean`, so here is a way that works by defining a method for objects of class `"numeric"`.

The example data is taken from [Waldi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66400615/8245406). Unlike in his answer, I negate `is.infinite` because `is.finite` will also return `TRUE` for missing values (`NA`) and argument `na.rm` will be irrelevant, missing values would always be removed. From the documentation `?is.finite`, my emphasis:

> Description
> is.finite and is.infinite return a vector of the same length as x, indicating which elements are finite **(not infinite and not missing)** or infinite.

In this description, the missing values part refers to the *finite* elements only and `is.infinite` expected behavior is to return `TRUE` for `-Inf/Inf` values but not `NA` nor `NaN`.

The code then becomes

```
mean.numeric <- function(x, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE, ...){
  x <- x[!is.infinite(x)]
  mean.default(x, trim = trim, na.rm = na.rm, ...)
}

y <- c(NA,Inf,NaN,1,2)

is.finite(y)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
!is.infinite(y)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 
mean(y)
#[1] NA
mean(y, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 1.5
```